# Audio visualizer on Artyom.js voice

Tags: javascript, audio, text-to-speech

how can i do some audio visualizer on Artyom.js's voice. I know how to do song visualizer, but the problem is I always used something like this.

```
new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)()
.createAnalyser()
.createGain()
```

But with Artyom I have this.

```
artyom.say(text)
```

So How can i access the text readed in real time for the audio vizualizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that ".say" call uses the browser's SpeechSynthesis API, which doesn't go through an audio context. Consider using something like [mespeak.js](https://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/) or Google TTS or whatnot, which you can pass through an Audio Context instead.